# Two different files giving same output despite having different codes - PyQT5 and Python

Tags: python, pyqt5

I have the two following files:

**datetime.py**

```
#! /usr/bin/python3.6

from PyQt5.QtCore import QDate, QTime, QDateTime, Qt

now = QDate.currentDate()

print(now)
print(now.toString(Qt.ISODate))
print(now.toString(Qt.DefaultLocaleLongDate))

datetime = QDateTime.currentDateTime()

print(datetime)
print(datetime.toString())

time = QTime.currentTime()

print(time)
print(time.toString(Qt.DefaultLocaleLongDate))
print("\n")
print("UTC Time: " + datetime.toUTC().toString(datetime.offsetFromUtc()))
```

It was running fine at the beginning, however, upon running it after a couple of times, I'm getting this result:

```
PyQt5.QtCore.QDate(2018, 8, 19)
2018-08-19
Sunday, August 19, 2018
PyQt5.QtCore.QDateTime(2018, 8, 19, 21, 47, 36, 885)
Sun Aug 19 21:47:36 2018
PyQt5.QtCore.QTime(21, 47, 36, 885)
9:47:36 PM MDT


UTC Time: Mon Aug 20 03:47:36 2018 GMT
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

The segmentation fault wasn't there at the beginning, it just started to pop up.

Then I created a new file:

**daysto.py**

```
#! /usr/bin/python3.6

from PyQt5.QtCore import QDate

xmas1 = QDate(2017, 12, 25)
xmas2 = QDate(2018, 12, 25)
daysToAnniversary1 = QDate(2018, 3, 3)
daysToAnniversary2 = QDate(2019, 3, 3)

now = QDate.currentDate()

daysPassed = xmas1.daysTo(now)

print(daysPassed)
```

The result I'm seeing is:

```
PyQt5.QtCore.QDate(2018, 8, 19)
2018-08-19
Sunday, August 19, 2018
PyQt5.QtCore.QDateTime(2018, 8, 19, 21, 47, 36, 885)
Sun Aug 19 21:47:36 2018
PyQt5.QtCore.QTime(21, 47, 36, 885)
9:47:36 PM MDT


UTC Time: Mon Aug 20 03:47:36 2018 GMT
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

So basically, I'm running two different files, but I still see the same output - which is weird because the second file is supposed to just give me a number. I copied the file to my home directory and it worked fine. However, as long as I'm in that directory, it's not working. I'm on Ubuntu 18 and my these files are `chmod +x`ed. Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

Comment: How do you execute the files? Are you using any IDE? Are you sure you're not running the same file?

Comment: @eyllanesc I'm using shebang line and then ./filename.py to run the script. I'm using VS code. I was not running the same file. User DYZ gave me the solution below. Thanks you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rename `datetime.py` to something else and remove directory `__pycache__`, if any. `datetime` is a standard Python module, but your namesake file is being imported instead of it, thus causing the duplicate output and the further crash.